# Push Notification function on Phonegap app using javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, push

I am building a push notification on Phonegap.  I reviewed the way of using the Push Plugin but it is not supporting windows phone.  I plan to use Javascript non stop looping by every 15 mins to query the Rest server and get the message back to display if any message is ready to published.  Do you think this is a good idea?  Will this cause any app leaking and slow down the app?

Comment: it's not really push if you poll. heh...

Comment: not really... most likely the OS will shut down the process few minutes after you close the app

Answer (score 0):

You will shoot yourself in the foot doing so.

Why? Your app will only be able to "receive" push notifications if it is active. If your **app is inactive**, you won't be able to poll for new notifications and therefore won't get any. So you're missing the actual great benefit of push notifications.

**Solution:** Pull the new version of the [Cordova Push Notifications Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). Support for Windows Phone 8 was added recently. That's the way to go.